# sqlite in native apps built using native app building kit

Tags: sqlite

Apps.

Our team has been tasked with creating a new app for the company - it will essentially be an offline catalogue.

The app needs to be able to access data offline thus needs to be a native app:
 - ideally using a database (containing 4000 - 5000 entries id's, geolocations, text descriptions of the entry)

However, we have been advised that if we create this app with a sizey sqlite database we may lead into performance issues.

I was just wondering if anyone had created any similar apps and found performance issues on any smartphones. Or is an sqlite database on a smartphone quite responsive?

Comment: 5000 entries should be no problem for SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Large amounts of data will lead to problems if you have queries like

```
SELECT * FROM everything
```

and then try to display all results in a list view.

If individual queries do not need to handle large data sets, performance will be fine.
See [Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) for details.